# What is the most robust way to get the width/height of the browser window using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser, robustness

I am curently using the follownig conditions, but they aren't working across browsers or at all:

```
if (typeof (window.innerHeight) == 'number') {
    //Non-IE:
    //Perform operation using window.innerWidth/Height
} else if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {
    //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
    //Perform operation using document.documentElement.clientWidth/Height
} else if (document.body && (document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight)) {
    //IE 4 compatible
    //Perform operation using document.body.clientWidth/Height
}
```

I believe I am missing a condition or two - perhaps there is another common expression I haven't taken into account.

What do I need to add to make this complete?

Comment: Are you really still supporting IE4? The market share for IE<6 combined is somewhere around 1% isn't it?

Comment: @Josh.Trow: I pulled this off the internet somewhere - I'm just looking to support as many browsers as humanly possible. An extra condition for IE4 isn't really that much more complicated, eh?

Comment: IE 4 is an ancient mummy. It was old even when I was younger. I can't think of anybody still trying to support it. You too really should not think about it.

Comment: Maybe not but I see no point to having extraneous code floating around, all it does is reduce readability. I work on projects with thousands of files with thousands of lines of code each, and clarity is absolutely king but I suppose it depends on the project.

Comment: Also, this q is kind of a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833708/how-do-i-get-the-size-of-the-browser-window-using-prototype-js

Comment: @Josh.Trow: Oh, you're right, that code looks roughly identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better off wrapping the whole logic into a function, so you only have to  say `getWindowHeight()`

```
// cross browser window height
function getWindowHeight() {
  return window.innerHeight || 
         (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight) || 
         (document.body && document.body.clientHeight);
}
```

*[Tested](http://jsbin.com/ovemo3/2/): IE5.5+, FF 2+, Chrome, Opera*

But for an even more robust approach please visit the related comp.lang.javascript FAQ entry:
**[How do I find the size of the window?](http://jibbering.com/faq/#FAQ4_9)**

Answer (score 1):

Include jQuery in your pages and use `$(window).width()` and  `$(window).height()`.

Comment: Looking to do this in JavaScript, not JQuery.

Comment: JQuery is Javascript, and opensource. If you don't want full jQuery support you can look into the source how they implemented those methods.

Comment: @Mark: That is an excelent point. Thanks. I may very well do that, as the JQuery methods are probably the best example on the market.

Comment: I would argue that if someone asks for "javascript", they are not looking for a jquery solution, even if jquery runs in javascript and is open source.  Yes they can look at the source, but why not just give them that information?

Comment: @Giffyguy - Don't you dare believe that. Ever.

Comment: @galambalazs, can you elaborate on why he wouldn't ever believe that?

Comment: Just because a lot of people use something, doesn't mean that it's always correct. In fact jQuery had/has many problems. It took Resig years to remove user agent sniffing from his code. He even wrote a book full of misconceptions http://bit.ly/cV1mVU. Also it's got one of the worst selector engines out there with a fundamentally broken abstraction http://bit.ly/c0ZliK, http://bit.ly/c3oiQK, http://bit.ly/99xQLS. All I'm saying is that jQuery isn't that shiny as one might naively think. It's surely **not** *`"the best example on the market"`*.

Comment: Ok, can you suggest better alternative(s) with the functionality of jQuery?