# How to learn browser size with prototype js framework?

Tags: javascript, function, browser, prototypejs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the size of the browser window using Prototype.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833708/how-do-i-get-the-size-of-the-browser-window-using-prototype-js)

What is the function to use to get the browser size with prototype js framework?

Comment: Please look here => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833708/how-do-i-get-the-size-of-the-browser-window-using-prototype-js

Answer (score 0):

```
var viewport = document.viewport.getDimensions();
```

See [the API docs](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/document/viewport/getDimensions/).